# Installing Scrapy on Lion - libxml/xmlversion.h not Available

Tags: python, osx-lion, scrapy

I used home brew and install python with the `$ brew install python --framework`
Then I install `easy_install` to install pip,

After that as the Scrapy Website says, I use pip install to install Scrapy but looks like XCode is missing some libxml files.

```
In file included from src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:314:

/private/var/folders/h6/xl6c12wn67n_9j7jl60b_j843908_z/T/pip-build-auduwage/lxml/src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h:9:10: fatal error: 'libxml/xmlversion.h' file not found

#include "libxml/xmlversion.h"

         ^

1 error generated.

error: command '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: @birryree You have answered a question related to scrapy in past wonder if you had to solve this problem while installing scrapy.

Answer (score 8):

You must install package libxslt-dev

Answer (score 6):

You probably don't have xcode command line tools installed.  If you run:

```
xcode-select --install
```

from the command line xcode should prompt you to install them, and then try again.