# Using Scrapy with OS X 10.9

Tags: python, macos, scrapy

I recently updated from OS X 10.8 to OS X 10.9. It looks like the upgrade removed the previous version of Python and all the libraries that were installed. I am trying to re-install Scrapy on OS X 10.9 but I keep getting an error using both pip and easy_install.

Here is the error message I am encountering.

```
/private/tmp/pip_build_root/lxml/src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h:9:10: fatal error: 'libxml/xmlversion.h' file not found

#include "libxml/xmlversion.h"

         ^

1 error generated.

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

Does anyone know to resolve this or have a work around?

Comment: **removed**? That sounds bad..

Comment: Check this https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/371

Comment: And this thread too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17909691/installing-scrapy-on-lion-libxml-xmlversion-h-not-available

Comment: what's happening is that you don't have cc for installing libxml.

Comment: @PepperoniPizza How do I resolve that?

Comment: @fasouto the thread you provided doesn't answer the question..

Comment: @alKid In the first one they give a solution that may work(remove MAMP), in the second one  somebody recommend installing libxslt-dev.

Comment: I have never had MAMP installed, and installing that package through homebrew did not resolve the issue. I'm not really sure I know where to go from here, I really want to avoid doing a clean install of OS X if that would even help

Comment: You may find your answers on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548011/cannot-install-lxml-on-mac-os-x-10-9/19550278)

Comment: happened to me too after upgrading to OSX mavericks, install/upgrade the command line tools using xcode-select --install

Answer (score 2):

Some questions from osx 10.9. try `xcode-select --install`